# Why onToggle of FlutterSwitch does not work in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, switch-statement, toggle

I used same code in the different place, it is working but in here is not working. I do not understand the situation. Could you help me to solve this?
This is not working

```
void showFilters(){
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: col.mostDarkGrey
            ),
            height: height,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.8,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: col.mostLightPurpleAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: DefaultTextStyle(
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          child: Text(
                            'OPERATÖRLER',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                    width: width*.8,
                    height: height*.45,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      primary: false,
                      itemCount: MaintenanceApi.maintenanceUsers.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final employee = MaintenanceApi.maintenanceUsers;
                        return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: col.mostLightPurpleAccent,
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                                  width: 3,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                                    child: Text(
                                      '${employee[index].userName}',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  FlutterSwitch(
                                    width: width >= 750 ? width * .08 : width * .2,
                                    height: width >= 750 ? height * .04 : height * .05,
                                    activeColor: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                                    toggleSize: width >= 750 ? width * .04 : width * .08,
                                    value: employee[index].isActive!,
                                    borderRadius: height * .04,
                                    onToggle: (bool val) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        // debugPrint("1"+employee[index].isActive.toString());//false
                                        employee[index].isActive = val;
                                        // debugPrint("2"+employee[index].isActive.toString());//true
                                        employees[index].isActive = employee[index].isActive;
                                        // debugPrint("3"+employees[index].isActive.toString());//true
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                        );
                      })
                ),
],
            )
        )
    );
  }
```

I do not understand why setState is not working. I use debugPrint and debug the value is changing but it is not showing. Could you help me guys?

Comment: what exactly is not working? the onToggle callback or the the Switch render problems?

Comment: @Shashoug toggle is not switching on the screen. But value is changing

Comment: you should be more serious when dealing with setState(), so, you have to implement setState at the first line on onToggle callback.